# is there a way for keeping a variable from changing inside recursions, in haskell?

Tags: haskell, variables, element

i'm trying to define the isInfixOf function, and i came to a solution(hope it works good :-)),
but because of the recursion nature of haskell, i wrote another (help) function that
almost duplicate the code of the function isInfixOf.

this is the code:

myIsInfixOf :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
myIsInfixOf [] []   = True
myIsInfixOf [] list = True
myIsInfixOf list [] = False
myIsInfixOf listA listB | helpFunction listA listB == True = True
                        | otherwise =  myIsInfixOf listA (tail listB)

helpFunction :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
helpFunction [] []      = True
helpFunction [] list    = True
helpFunction list []    = False
helpFunction (x:xs)(y:ys) | x == y = helpFunction xs ys
                          | otherwise = False

i did the help function, because i need the first element of the myIsInfixOf Function, untouchable.
if i don't make this helpFunction, the first element of the function myIsInfixOf, always decrease by one element, which is not good, because i need to iterate throughout the whole second element of the function myIsInfixOf, and check for equality with the first element of it.
with the help of the helpFunction, my first element of the list is untouchable and just the second element is decreasing every recursion(which is good).

so, can i save somewhere, my first element of myIsInfixOf, without recode almost everything?

thanks. :-)

Comment: Doesn't `helpFunction` already implement all of the functionality of the isInfixOf predicate?

Comment: i think not :-).
myIsInfixof send the helpFunction both of the it's elements.
the help function examine if the first element is inside the second one.
if yes, i get True for answer.
if not, the function myIsInfixOf is called with the exactly first element, and the tail of the second element.
this way i examine the first element with the whole second element of the function.

Comment: There is never a reason to use `... == True`; `...` alone suffices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two functions aren't really all that similar, if you look at them. What is the same are the first three "trivial" cases, but the last case does different things in both functions. You could also leave out the first two cases in either of those functions since they check the same thing on the same lists. So `myIsInfixOf` also works like this:

```
myIsInfixOf :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
myIsInfixOf (a:as) [] = False
myIsInfixOf listA listB | helpFunction listA listB = True
                        | otherwise =  myIsInfixOf listA (tail listB)
```

This really isn't the same as `helpFunction`, and doesn't repeat any nontrivial code.

Also you really want the second function to work independently from the first, since you want to check for every position in `listB` if every character of `listA` matches those in `listB`. To do this in a imperative program you would need nested loops, here you need a nested recursion best done with a helper function like you did. The issue is not that `listA` would somehow be lost without the helpFunction, the problem is that the algorithm requires `helpFunction` to run over the list independently of `myIsInfixOf`.

If you want to avoid manually implementing the recursion of `myIsInfixOf` by using more functions from the standard library you could use [`any`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Prelude.html#v:any) and [`tails`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Data-List.html#v:tails). For `helpFunction` probably explicit recursion is the way to go, but you could simplify the whole last case to:

```
helpFunction (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x == y) && helpFunction xs ys
```

Comment: `myIsInfixOf [] []` should be `True`, but your version will return `False`.

Comment: OK, thanks for that.
i thought that it could be a better way for code that, but i understand that my way is good enough :-).

Comment: Do you even need the first clause in your definition of myIsInfixOf? I think you could just pass two empty lists on to helpFunction and it would be correct. Also, I think I would rewrite the second clause using `or`, because it would seem simpler, but that's more a personal preference thing.

Comment: @noahlavine: The problem is that `tail listB` will fail if `listB` is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Note that 1) you don't need the first clause in both cases, since `[] list` matches `[] []` as well and you return the same result; 2) `helpFunction listA listB == True` is the same as `helpFunction listA listB`.

```
myIsInfixOf :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
myIsInfixOf [] list = True
myIsInfixOf list [] = False
myIsInfixOf listA listB | helpFunction listA listB = True
                        | otherwise =  myIsInfixOf listA (tail listB)

helpFunction :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
helpFunction [] list    = True
helpFunction list []    = False
helpFunction (x:xs)(y:ys) | x == y = helpFunction xs ys
                          | otherwise = False
```

In the comment you said

> the help function examine if the first element is inside the second one.

Actually, it doesn't. It checks if the second argument *starts* with the first one. That's why you need a different function. So a better name for `helpFunction` is `myPrefixOf`. This should help you eliminate another clause from the definition of `myIsInfixOf`.

Comment: except that i already implemented also the myIsPrefixOf function :-),
but it didn't occur to me, to use it here, but as you said, it's the right help function here. thanks :-).

Answer (score 2):

In line with a few of the suggestions Alexey Romanov and sth made, this would be my initial take on rewriting it:

```
import Data.List

myIsInfixOf xs ys = any (myIsPrefixOf xs) (tails ys)

myIsPrefixOf [] _ = True
myIsPrefixOf (x:_) [] = False
myIsPrefixOf (x:xs) (y:ys) = x == y && myIsPrefixOf xs ys
```

To more directly answer your actual question, note two things about this version:

- You can kind of "save" the value of the first argument using partial application
- You can eliminate a lot of the redundant code by using built-in recursive functions

Comment: `tails` is pretty easy to define without `import Data.List`, too.  In any case, the standard library defines `isInfixOf` exactly like this, in terms of `any`, `isPrefixOf`, and `tails`, and defines `isPrefixOf` just like this too.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing 'element' and 'argument' in your question, at least in some places. Also, what do you mean by 'untouchable'?

To come back to your question: You can do a pattern match and keep the original argument around by using so-called at-patterns:

```
myIsInfixOf listA@(x:xs) listB@(y:ys) = ...
```

This lets you refer to the entire first argument as listA, the first element of listA as x and the tail as xs (and same for the second argument). Is that what you meant?

Comment: i didn't get(yet) to this at-pattern in the book i'm reading, so maybe in the future they will discuss this.

in untouchable, i mean that if i could leave the first element of the function(the list that i want to search for, in the second element(list) in the function) without changing, i didn't need another function.
because every recursion, the first element is decreasing in one, and i can't compare the original element again.

in your example, if i'm enter into recursion, the listA element is staying untouchable? i mean, it doesn't decrease itself every recursion?

:-)